# k3s containerd - https registry certificate

Tags: docker, kubernetes, k3s, containerd

I store my images in a private docker registry, through https with a self-signed certificate. For docker clients to accept the certificate, I just copied the `.crt` file to `/etc/docker/certs.d/registry.domain:5000/`, after which `docker pull registry.domain:5000/test-image` succeeds.

However, I would like to use the same registry in `k3s` with the included containerd runtime. Following this doc: https://github.com/containerd/containerd/blob/main/docs/cri/registry.md

1. I copied the `.crt` file to `/etc/containerd/certs.d/registry.domain:5000/ca.crt`
2. added these lines to `/var/lib/rancher/k3s/agent/etc/containerd/config.toml`:

```
[plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry]
 config_path = "/etc/containerd/certs.d"
```

After these changes, when I try to scale up a pod with an image from the registry, I still get this error:
`...failed to do request: Head \"https://registry.domain:5000/v2/hello-web/manifests/latest\": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"`

How can I configure containerd included in k3s to use custom certificates for registries?

Comment: "self-signed certificate" public certificates are free now, so the easist solution is to use let's encrypt to provision them for your domain and be done with it